Can we change the example question from our tour?
The example question from our tour is a really bad example of the questions we want on this site.

Could we please replace it with another highly voted question with multiple answers, such as:

Does evidence support Maslow's Hierarchy of Needs?
Is The magical number 7 still valid?
How are newly created neurons recruited into existing networks?


I looked at the most upvoted questions and found these three questions that may be interesting (potentially after some minor editing):
Is multitasking a myth? (OP account is deleted)
What are good examples of applying dynamical systems in cognitive science? (answers are too long)
Can response time be incorporated into signal detection theory? (does not show in list, despite seemingly fitting the profile. Not sure what is missing)
What is the psychological term for disregarding correct but unwanted information? (not suitable given deleted account of one user)
How to recognize contempt (as suggested by Steven; needs two non-fancy formatted and good quality answers)
Edit
Behind every question I list why they are or aren't suitable (anymore). The bold question is my favorite potential question. 

Given @gerry's answer, I think the last link is the only one elegible and even then, I'm not sure...

@Seanny123, What about some of us try to formulate a new, rather simple, question. Might not be the best content again, and we must make sure it gets 5 upvotes, but we can at least put in a reference in the answers.

@RobinKramer The one you just flagged could be such a one when beaten into shape. Just did a first attempt at doing so.
